# Why should Yitzchok have to give a brachah to the person whom he thought was Eisav, if he had wrongly suspected Yaakov?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot, yaakov-and-eisav

In the ספורנו on בראשית כז:כג

שעירות - וַיְבָרֲכֵהוּ. עַל שֶׁחֲשָׁדו שֶׁהָיָה רָאוּי לִקְלָלָה, כְּאָמְרו "וְהֵבֵאתִי עָלַי קְלָלָה, (פסוק יב), וְכֵן  אָמְרוּ זִכְרונָם לִבְרָכָה: (ברכות לא) שֶׁהַחושֵׁד אֶת חֲבֵרו בְּדָבָר שֶׁאֵין בּו, שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לְפַיְּסו, וְלא עוד אֶלָּא  שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לְבָרְכו...

Seforno Beraishes 27:23
[After Yitzchok felt the hands of Yaakov and found them to be] "hairy" - He blessed him. Because he [had] suspected him of being worthy of a curse, as it states (pasuk 12) "and I will bring upon myself a curse". And so have they [Chacamim] OBM said" That one who suspects another of something that he has not [done], must appease him. Moreover, the one who suspected him must bless him"...

Question: If Yitzchok originally suspected that the person who was standing in front of him was really Yaakov, and he was lying and calling himself Eisav, then the one whom he wrongly suspected and thought was worthy of curse was Yaakov and not Eisav. So why then, when he feels his hands and [now thinks that he] realizes his mistake and that he is really Eisav, should he give the Brachah to him [who he thinks is Eisav], and not to Yaakov whom he had wrongly suspected?

Comment: Very confusing but good question!

Comment: @ezra Now that you got it, do you think you could/ should reword it to make it less confusing?

Comment: Agreed ... I've read it about 4 times and I'm *ungeboodled*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yitzchak suspected that the person in front of him was worthy of a curse. When he realized that that suspicion was in error, he had to bless him.